# Is there a name for misspelling or mispronouncing a word by confusing it with a cognate?

Tags: terminology

For example, tonight's news broadcast on Public Television identified a man selling fish and chips as a *restauranteur*.

Comment: Why was this a mistake? What cognate was this confused with? Please explain.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is probably a [**malapropism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism), from Sheridan. However, that doesn't fit the example in the text. Fish and chip restaurants are quite common.

Comment: http://grammarist.com/spelling/restaurateur/

Comment: [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/restauranteur) would not agree that the word is misspelled nowadays: restauranteur _noun_ another name for restaurateur.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth has informed me that restauranteur is an acceptable alternative for restaurateur. So I have erred. People who pronounce "erred as "aired" are making the mistake I have in mind by mixing up err with error, as are those who put an extra a in bestial or an extra i in granary. ( I don't have access to Collins English dictionary, but I'm hoping at least one of beastial and grainary is incorrect.

Comment: As far as I know, none of those pronunciations is generally considered incorrect, although opinions among pedants may vary. (I'm a bit of a pedant, so I do appreciate learning about "restaurateur" and "granary" from your question and comments.)

Comment: @sumelic I may be a pedant: I recall an expert set theorist's calling my definition of "equation" Pickwickian. For sure I'm an old timer, and I'm just stuck with the rules I grew up with many decades ago. I guess there's no point in adding that I think there's no "vague" in "vagary" or "pious" in "impious." I'd like to chat privately with you, if you're willing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A specialized example is a [mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen), "a mishearing or misinterpretation of a phrase as a result of near-homophony, in a way that gives it a new meaning".

The term originated when, as a girl, Sylvia Wright was exposed to the poem "The Bonny Earl o' Moray" and heard the lines

> They hae slain the Earl o' Moray,
>
> And laid him on the green

as

> They hae slain the Earl o' Moray,
>
> And Lady Mondegreen

which she much preferred.